# HttpResponse and HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I currently have an application which calls `httpResponse.End()` to end a request, however, following Microsoft's recommendations and to keep it from throwing an exception I am trying to change it to `HttpContext.CompleteRequest`,

My question however is, what is the `HttpContext` object? And where do I get it inside the controller?

EDIT: I initially posted a question that was similar, in order to change the title I deleted the question and tried asking it again (there is probably a better way). StackOverflow prevented me from doing it because it was a 'duplicate', although I already deleted it. Adding this, so it allows me to post.

Comment: The correct way is to edit your question.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that right after doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext`

It is static (Or at least has the *appearance* of being so) and accessible within **MVC Controllers**, **ASP.NET web forms** and I would assume ASP.NET web pages (have not used).

The `Current` property gives you access to Session, Cache and all the things you associate with an **active Web context**.

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current will bring you the current httpContext